# Stochastic VRP: Sources of uncertainty and modeling approaches

Tags: vehicle-routing, stochastic-process

In one of the archived research topics of mine, I tried to model and solve **SVRP**s using *Multiple Tandem Queues*. I have two related questions:

1. What are the sources for uncertainty in Stochastic VRPs? In other words, what causes the stochasticity in VRPs?
2. Which of those factors has been most/least studied?

I couldn't find any paper implementing **any queue theory ideas** in the modeling of the stochastic VRPs. I appreciate suggestions in this regard as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The source of uncertainty is usually customer demand, travel time, service time at the location (during pick up or serving the customer), or presence of the customer (customers may not be available to receive their orders). As mentioned in the paper:

> Capacitated vehicle routing problem with stochastic demand has been by far the most studied version of the problem.

This paper "[The stochastic vehicle routing problem, a literature review, part I: models](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13676-016-0100-5)" reviews these different cases. In [another review](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13676-016-0099-7), the same authors discuss different solution methods.

About queueing theory idea for solving SVRP, you can take a look at this paper: "[Vehicle routing with dynamic travel times: a queueing approach](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0377221707003116)" where:

> a vehicle routing problem with dynamic travel times due to potential traffic congestion is considered. The approach developed introduces mainly the traffic congestion component based on queueing theory.

Comment: I will look at the papers, thanks for the suggestion. Stochasticity sources are almost all that I thought.

Comment: @OguzToragay I edited my answer to include a link for a paper that uses a queueing theory approach

Comment: I also edited my question to emphasize the modeling approach which should be based on queue theory models.